# yt_search prints in console. How to remove it?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python and i'm using a library called "youtube_dl" to search a song from youtube and play it in a voice channel.
It works fine, but everytime i write the command and the bot searches on yt, it prints in the console a big and annoying text. How can I avoid this? Thank you!

```
29/09/2021 21:04:48 - Liuk23#3966 looked for the next song in the queue. (what I actually want to print)
29/09/2021 21:04:58 - Liuk23#3966 added "bach" to the queue. (what I actually want to print)
[download] Downloading playlist: bach
[youtube:search] query "bach": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist bach: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] 6JQm5aSjX6g: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video 6JQm5aSjX6g because of --no-playlist
[download] Finished downloading playlist: bach
29/09/2021 21:05:10 - Liuk23#3966 offlined the bot. (what I actually want to print)
```

The code i'm using is from this guy on youtube: https://youtu.be/i0nNPidYQ2w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by editing the ydl_options.
You just need to add "'quiet':'True'".

```
self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True', 'quiet':'True'}
YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS)
```